# How could I use TSX components to write to canvas?

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I'm a beginner at React and I got stuck on this. I want to be able to describe a canvas layout with TSX, and my idea to do that was something like this.

Scene File

```
export default function* first(scene: Scene) {
      let test = <Rect width={320} height={320}></Rect>;
      scene.add(test);
    }
```

Scene Definition

```
class Scene {
    constructor(){
        ctx = canvasRef.current?.getContext("2d");
    }
  add(elem: JSX.Element) {
    if (ctx == null) {
      return;
    }
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

Rect Definition

```
const Rect = ({width, height}:RectProps) => {
  console.log("This does not log because it is not getting rendered")
  if (ctx == null) {
    return <></>;
  }
  ctx.rect(0,0, width, height)
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  return <></>
};
```

But this approach doesn't work. What would be a better way to model canvas layouts like this with TSX? I haven't been able to come up with many ideas, other than trying to parse TSX, but this doesn't seem like it will scale well.

Comment: What exactly is your goal here?

Comment: My goal here is to be able to describe the scene in the scene file, and then have that be represented on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use class for this. All thats really needed is `React.useRef`

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-oskar-l7pu56?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
type RectProps = {
  width: number;
  height: number;
};

const Rect = ({ width, height }: RectProps) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvasRef.current?.getContext('2d');
    if (!ctx) return;

    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  }, [height, width]);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={width} height={height} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return <Rect width={100} height={100} />
}
```

Comment: A class is preferable as I would need to hook into each element. to update other parts of the UI, and that way I won't have to update from so many locations.